# Extra forward slash in jquery, ajax, json

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, url

Here is the response I am getting:

JBossWeb/2.0.1.GA - Error report

## HTTP Status 404 - /demo//ajax/operators

**type** Status report

**message** /demo//ajax/operators

**description** The requested resource (/demo//ajax/operators) is not available.

#### JBossWeb/2.0.1.GA

The problem lies in the double forward slash in the url. HTTP Status 404 - /demo//ajax/operators

How do I fix/resolve this issue?

Here is the code:

```
function removeOperator(opId) {

    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to remove the operator?\n' +
                'Ok=Remove\nCancel=Don\'t Remove')) {

        $.ajax({

            url: '/demo/datamgmt/updatePricingRule.do',

            data: {
                method: 'removeOperator',
                operatorId: opId
            },

            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                alert('Error: ' + textStatus);

            },

            dataType: 'json',

            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

                if (data.result == 'success') {

                    $('#operator_' + opId).remove();

                } else if (data.result == 'fail') {
                    alert(data.failMsg);
                }
            }
        });

    }
}

function processOperatorClick(opId) {

    $.ajax (
    {
        url: '/demo/datamgmt/updatePricingRule.do',

        data: {
            method: 'addOperator',
            operatorId: opId
        },

        statusCode: {
            404: function() {
                    alert( "page not found" );
                }   
        },

        dataType: 'json',

        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

            if (data.result == 'success') {

                var operator = data.operator;
                var $operatorRow = $('<tr />', 
                    {
                        'class': 'list-item',
                        'data-id': operator.id,
                        'id' : 'operator_' + operator.id
                    }).css('cursor', 'pointer');
                $operatorRow.append($('<td />').html(operator.customerNo == '' ? '&nbsp;' : operator.customerNo));      
                $operatorRow.append($('<td />').text(operator.label));              
                $operatorRow.append($('<td />', {'align': 'right'}).text(operator.address.city + ', ' + operator.address.state.id));

                $operatorRow.appendTo($('#associatedOperatorsContainer_tbody'));

                $operatorRow.click(
                    function() {
                        removeOperator(operator.id);
                    }
                );
            } else if (data.result == 'fail') {
                alert('Error Message:\n' + data.failMsg);
            }

        }   

    }); 

}

$(document).ready(
    function() {

    $('.operator').click(
        function() {
            removeOperator($(this).data('id'));             
        });

    $('#addOperatorsButton').click(function() {

        var $div = $('#operatorSearchContainer');

        if (!$div.length) {
            $div = $('<div />');
            $div.attr('id', 'operatorSearchContainer');
            $div.dialog(
                {
                    autoOpen: false,
                    modal: 'true',
                    title: 'Search Operators',
                    width: 550,
                    height: 600
                }
            );

            $.ajax(
            {
                url: '/demo/ajax/operators',

                data: {
                    mode: 'showform'
                },

                statusCode: {
                    404: function() {
                            alert( "page not found" );
                        }   
                },

                dataType: 'html',

                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    $div.html(data);
                }

            });
        }

        if (!$div.dialog('isOpen'))
            $div.dialog('open');

    });
});
```

and the HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td style="padding-left: 30;"><div class="maxheight-small">
        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" class="list" id="operatorsContainer" width="400">
            <c:choose>
                <c:when test="${not empty pricingRuleForm.map.operators}">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="2">Operator</th>
                            <th align="right">Address</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="associatedOperatorsContainer_tbody">
                        <nested:iterate property="operators" indexId="index" id="op">
                            <tr id="operator_${index}" class="non-select-list-item">
                                <td width="3%"><nested:hidden property="id" />
                                    <a href="#" onclick="return removeOperator(${index});">
                                    <html:img page="/images/sm_x_15x15.gif" module="/" width="15" height="15" border="0" /></a></td>
                                <td><nested:write property="label" /></td>
                                <td align="right">
                                    &nbsp;${op.map.address.map.formattedAsHTML}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </nested:iterate>
                    </tbody>
                </c:when>
                <c:otherwise>
                    <tr><td><i>No operators assigned to this rule.</i></td></tr>
                </c:otherwise>
            </c:choose>
        </table></div></td>
    </tr>
```